# Laplace transform of the derivative of a function with jump discontinuity at t=0

Tags: continuity, laplace-transform, piecewise-continuity, inverse-laplace

While trying to find the inverse laplace transform of $F(s)=s\log\frac{s-1}{s+1}$, I first calculated at the inverse laplace transform of $$G(s)=\log\frac{s-1}{s+1}$$ which came out to be $$g(t)=\frac{e^{-t}-e^t}{t}$$ (ignoring the heaviside function, I don't think it would make a difference here.)

Now, to find the inverse laplace transform of $F(s)=sG(s)$ I would usually use the theorem $$\mathcal{L}\{g'(t)\}=sG(s)-g(0)$$ But here $g$ has a jump discontinuity at $t=0$ $$g(0^+)=2\neq g(0^-)=0$$ Initially I just used $g(0^+)=-2$ in place of $g(0)$ which resulted in $$f(t)=g'(t)-2\delta(t)$$Besides the fact that $2\delta(t)$ term is not in the answer given in the textbook, it doesn't make much sense to me either, we can only speak of $g'(t)$ for $t>0$. I assume I was wrong to use $g(0^+)=-2$ in the equation, so what would be the correct method to find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sG(s)\}$ when $g(t)$ is discontinuous at $t=0$? Could the issue here be $g(t)$ itself, that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\log\frac{s-1}{s+1}\}$ is not in fact $\frac{e^{-t}-e^t}{t}$? I ask this because I am not entirely sure whether $g(t)$ would satisfy this condition for the existence of a laplace transform:

> $f(t)$ is piecewise continuous on $0\leq t\leq A$ for every $A>0$

I will edit this question to add my derivation of $g(t)$ if needed, any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend forcing derivative's theorem in these cases because it really gets messy, specially when considering generalized functions and their initial conditions.

I would go this way using convolution:

$$F(s)=s \log \frac{s-1}{s+1}$$

$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{s\} * \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\log \frac{s-1}{s+1} \right\} = \delta'(t) * \frac{e^{-t}-e^t}{t} = \int_0^t \delta'(t-x) \frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{x} dx$$

and to solve the integral, I'll use the filter property of dirac's delta function and its derivatives

$$\int_0^t \frac{d^1}{dx^1}\big( \delta(t-x) \big) \frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{x} dx = (-1)^1 \frac{d^1}{dx^1} \left. \left( \frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{x} \right) \right|_{x=t} =  \frac{e^{-t}(t+1)+e^t(t-1)}{t^2}$$

mind that $\delta'(t-x)=\delta'(x-t)$ for the integral purposes and because $x$ and $t$ take positive values.

my answer is slightly diferent form what Wolfram Alpha computes. But maybe this result is right, at least for a part of it. Tell me if this answer is the one given to you. And please anyone let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: The result is correct, if you change the sign ($\delta'(t-x)=-\delta'(x-t)$). Direct check gives (integrating by part)
$$-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}(t+1)+e^t(t-1)}{t^2}e^{-st}dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\big(e^{-t(s+1)}(t+1)+e^{-t(s-1)}(t-1)\big)$$
$$=-s\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t(s-1)}-e^{-t(s+1)}}{t}dt=s\ln\frac{s-1}{s+1}$$
where the Frullani integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral was used in the last line.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Your first integral is equal to $F(s) + 2$ (which is as expected, since the Bromwich integral of $(F(s) + 2) e^{t s}$ converges and the Bromwich integral of $F(s) e^{t s}$ diverges). From this we can obtain the correct answer, which contains a $\delta(t)$ term. The answer can also be obtained from $\mathcal L[f'](s) = s \mathcal L[f](s)$ (which is the correct distributional formula) or from convolving with $\delta'$ if we keep in mind that $(e^{-t} - e^t)/t$ is in fact $H(t) (e^{-t} - e^t)/t$ and compute the distributional derivative and the distributional convolution accordingly.

Comment: @Maxim, thank you for pointing out my mistake. Indeed, I lost the term which gives 2. Integrating by part,
$$-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}(t+1)+e^t(t-1)}{t^2}e^{-st}dt=s\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t(s+1)}-e^{-t(s-1)}}{t}dt$$
$$+\int_0^\infty \Big(e^{-t(s+1)}(s+1)+e^{-t(s-1)}(s-1)\Big)dt=s\ln\frac{s-1}{s+1}+2$$